# ExtJS: Get absolute position of dynamic containers

Tags: extjs, containers, positioning, absolute

i need to find out the absolute position of dynamically created containers, which are added to a panel.

```
var activityContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    html: activityName,
    width: ACTIVITY_WIDTH,
    height: ACTIVITY_HEIGHT,
    margin: topMargin + ' 0 0 0',
    cls: 'activity',
    listeners: {
        render: function () {
             this.getEl().dom.title = 'Name: ' + activity.name + reqQuicktip;
        },
        afterrender: function() {
             console.log('Y: ' + this.getEl().getTop() +' X: '+ this.getEl().getLeft())
        }
     }
})

tradePanel.add(activityContainer);
```

I´ve learned that i only can get the position when the containers have been already rendered. Thus i use the afterrender listener. The methods getY()/getTop() and so on are not working the way i expected them to do. I always get 1 for my x coordinate and no adequate y coordinates.

What am i missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are implementing your panel, the keyword `this` might be returning the information for the wrong panel.

You create your listener like this:

```
afterrender: function(component) {
    console.log('Y: ' + component.getY() +' X: '+ component.getX());
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you to test: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cud

Comment: Ok. I´ve implemented it that way but still get the same results.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a fiddle with your problem so I could take a look?

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/d01

I realize that i get positions relative to the last item in the panel, but not absolute ones. =/